# Filtering in Telerik Kendo Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

Hi I have a simple select in my mvc view....

```
<select id="msProducts" multiple style="width:100%;"></select>
```

which is converted to a Kendo Multiselect using Javascript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //products multi-select
        $("#msProducts").kendoMultiSelect({
            placeholder: "Select Product(s)",
            dataTextField: "ProductNameText",
            dataValueField: "ProductNameValue",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "Home/Products"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

});
```

My Contoller has:

```
'GET: Home/Products
<HttpGet>
Function Products() As JsonResult
    Dim DiaryProductList As List(Of ProductsModel) = ProductsModel.GetProducts
    Return Json(DiaryProductList , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

My ProductsModel Class is:

```
Public Class ProductsModel

    Public Property ProductNameText As String

    Public Property ProductNameValue As String

    Public Shared Function GetProducts() As List(Of ProductsModel)
        Dim ProductList = New List(Of ProductsModel)
        Dim dc As New DBDataContext
        Try
            Dim ProductsQuery = (From pIn dc.Products
                                Where p.ProductStatus <> "discontinued"
                                Select New With {.ProductNameValue = p.ProductName,
                                    .ProductNameText = p.ProductName}).OrderBy(Function(lst) lst.ProductNameValue)
            For Each r In ProductsQuery
                ProductList.Add(New ProductsModel() With {.ProductNameValue = r.ProductNameValue,
                                  .ProductNameText = r.ProductNameText})
                Next

           Catch ex As Exception
                ProductList.Add(New ProductsModel() With {.ProductNameValue = "",
                                  .ProductNameText = ex.Message})
            Finally
                dc.Connection.Close()
            End Try
            Return ProductList
    End Function
End Class
```

My problem is that although the muti-select gets populated (with some 5000+ products) the dropdown is not filtering as a user types. For example if I beging typing the word CAKE. As soon as I type C the I-beam disappears and after a second or two the dropdown drops for a brief moment and then disappears clearing the multi-select completely. The only way I can populate at the moment is type the letter A, wait and then scroll through the complete list and select what I need, repeating for each item I need. Have I missed something? Should I introduce paging in order to limit the data?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. So my opinion is that it is because of larget data set. Check [this link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/too-many-options-in-multiselect) - they talk about performance problem in case of large data set. If you can, try specifiy [minLength](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-minLength) to 3 (or something) and maybe [autoBind](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-autoBind) to false to avoid initial data load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the links provided by Ademar I've changed my code so that I have the following which works....

```
//products multi-select


    // ms datasource
    var ms_dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "Home/Products",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    "ProductName": {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // ms widget options
    var ms_options = {
        autoBind: false,
        minLength: 4,
        maxSelectedItems: 25,
        dataTextField: "ProductName",
        dataValueField: "ProductName",
        filter: "contains",
        placeholder: "Select Product(s)",
        dataSource: ms_dataSource
    };

    // create ms widget
    $("#msProducts").kendoMultiSelect(ms_options);
```

I have also amended my Product Class so that it give just a list of product names that I use as both the tag text and value in the multiselect.